# How can I change a width of table Material UI / React?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm making an application with React.JS and Material UI.

I use the table component for my application. I could change the width of column but I cannot change the width of table.

The width of table should be as same as the width of header component.(Purple color).

How can I achieve this?

Please find the current view below.  I would appreciate any kind of advice. Thank you so much for your help in advance.

[image]

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
Table,
TableBody,
TableHeader,
TableHeaderColumn,
TableRow,
TableRowColumn,
} from 'material-ui/Table';
import Check from './img/check.png';
import Fail from './img/fail.png';
import Master from './img/Master.png';
import Visa from './img/Visa.png';
import Paypal from './img/Paypal.png';

class PaymentTable extends React.Component {
render() {
return(
  <Table>
  <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>
  <TableRow>
    <TableHeaderColumn></TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn>Today</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn>Payment Method</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn>Narrative</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn>Amount</TableHeaderColumn>
  </TableRow>
</TableHeader>
<TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn><img src={Check} alt="Check" className="Check"/>
</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>12N35, 22 March 2017</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn><img src={Master} alt="Master" 
    className="Master"/>MasterCard...4483</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Prestige Cosmetics, Total Intensity Eyeliner Long 
    Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)
   </TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>$912.51</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn><img src={Check} alt="Check" className="Check"/>
   </TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>12N35, 22 March 2017</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn><img src={Paypal} alt="Paypal" className="Paypal"/>PayPal</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Prestige Cosmetics, Total Intensity Eyeliner Long Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>$912.51</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn><img src={Check} alt="Check" className="Check"/></TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>12N35, 22 March 2017</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn><img src={Visa} alt="Visa" className="Visa"/>VISA...1532</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Prestige Cosmetics, Total Intensity Eyeliner Long Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>$912.51</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn><img src={Fail} alt="Fail" className="Fail"/></TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>12N35, 22 March 2017</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn><img src={Visa} alt="Visa" className="Visa"/>VISA...1532</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Prestige Cosmetics, Total Intensity Eyeliner Long Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>$912.51</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
     <TableRowColumn><img src={Check} alt="Check" className="Check"/></TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>12N35, 22 March 2017</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn><img src={Master} alt="Master" className="Master"/>MasterCard...4483</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Prestige Cosmetics, Total Intensity Eyeliner Long Lasting Intense Color, Deepest Black, 1.2 g (.04 oz)</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>$912.51</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
 </TableBody>
 </Table>
 );
 }
 }
 export default PaymentTable;
```

style.css

```
  .table {
   width: 1200px;
   }
```

** Edit **

I edited as per advice. Now, the width was widened but it does not cover the width of window. Instead, a slide bar appeared below the table..
[image]

Comment: you are not applying the style, try this: `<Table style={{ width: 1200 }}>` or `<Table className='table'`>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

overwrite the width using the `style={}` prop to the `Table` Component. An example would look like:

```js
<Table style={{ width: 1200 }}>
```

Comment: that'll work, but using `style` is not recommended, use `className` instead

Comment: ` <Table style={{ width: 1200 }}>  `  worked but it didn't cover the width of window...

Comment: @ayumi that wasn't your question. Your q read, "How can I change a width of table Material UI / React?" To cover the width of the window, I suggest using percentages as your unit of measurement. Assuming the header and the table have the same parent you could probably just set to 100%

Comment: If following the material design system, should the width of the table not be set as a pixel count, but a number of columns or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

material UI has a `<TableContainer></TableContainer>` component that you can size and will allow the table inside to overflow if the content is too big

It also keeps the table header at the top if you use `stickyHeader` on the table